# Quadratic equation, cannot solve it while using a technique that doesn't use bhaskara

Tags: quadratics

My teacher taught how to solve squared equations without bhaskara. It's a completely new technique for me. Actually I solve only 2 problems till now. I am having a hard time solving the last one of the exercise list. Below I will show where I am stuck. Excuse me if I use terms that are not right, I am not certain how to say them in english.

14X² -43x + 20 = 0
because we have (+20) the two factors will have the same sign.

bellow I am turning 20 into products

```
14X² -43x + 20 = 0
            1 - 20
            2 - 10
            4 - 5
```

now I turng 14X² into products

```
14X² -43x + 20 = 0
x - 14x       1 - 20
2x - 7x       2 - 10
              4 - 5
```

Now I need to multiply the factors of x and +20 and sum them to get -43. In other words I need to find the maching pairs. But there's not matching pairs. Apparently. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The key point is that $20$ has negative factors too: $(-1) \cdot (-20)$, $(-2) \cdot (-10)$ and $(-4) \cdot (-5)$ are also factorizations of it. Anyway the overwhelming majority of the time if I were asked to factorize $ax^2+bx+c$ where $a \neq 1$ I would just use the quadratic formula to find the roots and then reconstruct the factors from the roots.

Comment: I multiply them for what x factors so that the sum is -43?

Comment: It winds up being $(7x-4)(2x-5)$ in the end. Each of the two factors of $20$ multiplies with one of the two factors of $14$.

Comment: Yes, I couln't see it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$14x^2-35x-8x+20=0$$
$$\implies 7x(2x-5)-4(2x-5)=0$$
$$\implies(7x-4)(2x-5)=0$$

Now you can easily find the roots.

---

*(No need to read further if you are good with the middle term factorization)*

Some more tips about using the technique - **Middle term Factorization**

> In India, we are taught this method before Bhaskara. Some points that
> may help you in splitting up easily
>
> 1. Make the coefficient of $x^2$ positive. In most of the cases you have a positive coefficient, but if they give you a negative
>    coefficient, then you can multiply both sides by $-1$. Now the
>    equation would look like $ax^2±bx+c$ or $ax^2±bx-c$ where $a$, $b$ and
>    $c$ are positive numbers
> 2. Prime factorize $a×c$.
> 3. Now, if the sign of $c$ is positive, then the splitting is to be done by addition. If the sign of $c$ is negative, then it is to be
>    done by subtraction.
> 4. Combine all the factors in two numbers in such a way that they either add up or their difference is $b$ (the addition or subtraction
>    is to be decided by point 3.)
>
> For instance, $$14x^2-43x+20$$
>
> Step 1 - Already done
>
> Step 2 - $14×35=2×2×2×5×7$ . So the factors are $2,2,2,5,7$
>
> Step 3 - As the sign of $c$ is positive, so the splitting is to be
> done by addition.
>
> Step 4 - This is to be totally done by hit-and-trial. However the
> third point helps us that both the factors must be less than 43. We
> have to only check by addition, etc. It can be easily spotted that
> $43=35+8$
>
> Another example: $$7\sqrt2x^2+10x-4\sqrt2$$
>
> Step 1 - Done
>
> Step 2 - $7\sqrt2×4\sqrt2=2×2×2×7$
>
> Step 3 - Factorization to be done by subtraction. So one of the
> numbers must be greater than $10$
>
> Step 4 - $14-4=10$

Comment: Great method... never saw that the sign of c could be so important